# Save an input image in localStorage and then retrieve it using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, file-upload, local-storage, session-storage

I'm uploading an image with some other information and then I want to save them all together (possibly in an array) in localStorage.

How can I retrieve that image in input and save it together with the other info using only JS? The code I'm using to upload the image is below (which I got it from another Stackoverflow question, and which also works).

```
function onFileSelected(event) {
  var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  var imgtag = document.getElementById("food");
  imgtag.title = selectedFile.name;

  reader.onload = function(event) {
    imgtag.src = event.target.result;
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
}
```

html:

```
<div class="immagine_cibo">
      <input type="file" onchange="onFileSelected(event)">
      <img id="food" height="200" width="250">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you have "imgtag.src = event.target.result",  event.target.result is a string of base64 encoded data. you can just save it in the localstore with localStorage.setItem('myPic', event.target.result);

If you want to save an array, you'll need to json.encode it first, as localStorage can only save strings.